# Подскажите PHP-фреймворк для начинающего

Tags: framework, php, фреймворк, mysql

Привет! Подскажите PHP-фреймворк типа `CodeIgniter`'а, чтобы писать небольшие сайты с админкой и т.д..

Почему для начинающего? Потому что ранее не имел опыта написания проектов на фреймворках.
Есть знания ООП, MVC.

Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот с кодигнайтера и начните. Он достаточно прост, чтобы привыкнуть.
После него можно переходить на Yii или Zend: проблем особых не возникнет.

Comment: А что-то еще есть типа него?

Comment: добавить то особо не чего.

Comment: @Lektor, вряд ли. Пожалуй, он самый простой. По крайней мере, из распространенных.

Comment: @Lektor, Kohana - внучек Codeigniter-a =) хорошая вещь

Comment: Ну, я бы сказал, что Kohana погостил у бабушки на лето и хорошенько поправился.

Comment: Я бы еще посоветовал Laravel хотя версия 4 немного потолстела но 3 версия в Русском сообществе распространена а там все достаточно просто ну и мне больше чем CodeIgniter нравится хотя лично мое мнениею

Answer (score 1):

Да начинайте с [CodeIgniter](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter). На него много русской документации, к тому же он интуинтивно понятный и простой. Вообщем не надо искать информации по нему. Все изложенно и понятно... Так что юзайте его на здоровье.